# Use of Spies for detecting method calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm new to RSpec.  I'm using the following (correct) piece of spec code for making sure that the methods `find` and `same_director` are called in the tested controller:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe MoviesController do
    describe 'Searching movies for same director: ' do
        before :each do
            @movie1 = instance_double('Movie', id:1, title:'movie1')
            @movie2 = instance_double('Movie', id:2, title:'movie2')
            @any_possible_id = 1
        end
        it 'should call the model method that finds the movie corresponding to the passed id.' do
            allow(@movie1).to receive(:same_directors).and_return [@movie1,@movie2]
            expect(Movie).to receive(:find).with(@any_possible_id.to_s).and_return @movie1
            get :directors, :id=>@any_possible_id
        end
        it 'should call the model method that finds the movies corresponding to the same director.' do
            expect(@movie1).to receive(:same_directors).and_return [@movie1,@movie2]
            allow(Movie).to receive(:find).with(@any_possible_id.to_s).and_return @movie1
            get :directors, :id=>@any_possible_id
        end
```

This is working fine, but as you can see, the two `it`-clauses contain a repeated `get :directors, :id=>@any_possible_id` line.  Given the order of the statement in the controller (see the controller code at the end of the question), the `get` has to appear at the end of the `it`-clause.  The challenge is to DRY it out by moving it to the `before`-clause.
Of course, the best solution is to just move it to an `after`-clause (I realized that while I was writing the question, I did it and it works.)  But what I want now is to understand why my use of Spies here is not working.

My (failing) attempt with Spies is:

```
describe MoviesController do
    describe 'Searching movies for same director: ' do
        before :each do
            @movie1 = instance_double('Movie', id:1, title:'movie1')
            @movie2 = instance_double('Movie', id:2, title:'movie2')
            @any_possible_id = 1
            @spyMovie = class_spy(Movie)
            @spymovie1 = instance_spy(Movie)
            get :directors, :id=>@any_possible_id
        end
        it 'should call the model method that finds the movie corresponding to the passed id.' do
            allow(@spymovie1).to receive(:same_directors)#.and_return [@movie1,@movie2]
            expect(@spyMovie).to have_received(:find).with(@any_possible_id.to_s)#.and_return @movie1
        end
        it 'should call the model method that finds the movies corresponding to the same director.' do
            expect(@spymovie1).to have_received(:same_directors)#.and_return [@movie1,@movie2]
            allow(@spyMovie).to receive(:find).with(@any_possible_id.to_s)#.and_return @movie1
        end
```

Now, there might be several problems with this second piece of code, but the error I am getting when running `rspec` is:

```
  1) MoviesController Searching movies for same director:  should call the model method that finds the movie corresponding to the passed id.
     Failure/Error: expect(@spyMovie).to have_received(:find).with(@any_possible_id.to_s)#.and_return @movie1
       (ClassDouble(Movie) (anonymous)).find("1")
           expected: 1 time with arguments: ("1")
           received: 0 times
     # ./spec/controllers/movies_controller_spec.rb:32:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) MoviesController Searching movies for same director:  should call the model method that finds the movies corresponding to the same director.
     Failure/Error: expect(@spymovie1).to have_received(:same_directors)#.and_return [@movie1,@movie2]
       (InstanceDouble(Movie) (anonymous)).same_directors(*(any args))
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
     # ./spec/controllers/movies_controller_spec.rb:35:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So, you can see that the calls to `:find` and to `:same_directors` are not being detected when I use the spies.

I couldn't get the answer in [rspec.info](http://rspec.info/documentation/3.4/rspec-mocks/#label-Message+Expectations) nor in [relishapp](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-4/docs/basics/spies).  I would very much appreciate it if you can suggest something. Thanks!

In case you need it, this is the controller:

```
  def directors
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    @movies = @movie.same_directors
    if (@movies-[@movie]).empty?
      flash[:notice] = "'#{@movie.title}' has no director info"
      redirect_to movies_path
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a relevant question: besides testing its behavior, one might want to make sure that certain controller methods are called.  For example, if those methods are from legacy code, you want to make sure via a self-checking test that someone else is not going to come and substitute her own methods in the controller. (Thank you anyway max, I appreciate your time).

This is the code that answers the question:

```
before :each do
    @movie1 = spy('Movie')
    allow(Movie).to receive(:find).and_return @movie1
    @any_possible_id = 1
    get :directors, :id=>@any_possible_id
end
it 'should call the model method that finds the movie corresponding to the passed id.' do
    expect(Movie).to have_received(:find).with(@any_possible_id.to_s)
end
it 'should call the model method that finds the movies corresponding to the same director.' do
    expect(@movie1).to have_received(:same_directors)
end
```

**Explanation**

Line 2 - `@movie1` is defined as a [spy](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-4/docs/basics/spies#using-a-spy) out of the class `Movie`.  Being a spy, we can use it later in `expect(@movie1).to have_received(:anything)`.  If `@movie1` is defined as a `double` then it [becomes necessary to use](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-4/docs/basics/allowing-messages) an `:allow` clause to allow it to receive the method `anything` (or "message", as the parlance of the docs).

Line 3 - **This line is the key for explaining the error** thrown by RSpec.  The `.and_return @movie1` is fundamental for telling RSpec that `@movie1` is playing the role of `@movie` in the controller (see the controller code at the end of the question).  RSpec establishes this match from seeing that `Movie.find` in the controller returns `@movie`, as specified in this `allow` statement.  The reason for the error in the question is not that `Movie` or `@movie` were not receiving the specified methods in the controller; the reason is that RSpec was not matching `Movie` and `@movie1` in the spec with the real `Movie` and `@movie` in the controller.

The rest is self-explanatory.  By the way, I came with other ways of writing this test, but this one with the use of the spy is the most compact one.